# Data conversion failed. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, webmatrix

Hello i recently got a problem in my Asp. Net C# 4 application. I am getting values from adress and then putting they into database. But framework give me "*Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]*" error. 
Here is my code:

```
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
var insert = db.Execute("INSERT INTO Downloads (ID, Name, Url, Size) VALUES ('@1', '@2', '@3', '@4')", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["fileid"]), Request.QueryString["name"], Request.QueryString["url"], Request.QueryString["size"]);
```

Where **ID** is **int** and **Name, Url, Size** is **ntext**. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter markers that the Database helper accepts must start at 0

```
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
var insert = db.Execute("INSERT INTO Downloads (ID, Name, Url, Size) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)", Request["fileid"], Request["name"], Request["url"], Request["size"]);
```

Comment: @Mike: I don't understand. Why should the parameters be named this way? Can't he use named parameters like `@fileid`, `@name`, `@url`, and `@size`? Is this a `WebMatrix` or `Access` db thing?

Comment: @jp2code: it's a WebMatrix.Data.Database helper thing. Parameter values are passed to an Execute, Query, or other method as an array, and matched to a dynamically generated DbParameter object according to their element index. Array indexes start at zero.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID` column is an integer then don't wrap the value in quotes:

`'@1'` should be `@1`

**Note:** What you have here is a SQL injection vulnerability.  *Never* directly use query string input (or form input, or any user input) in a query like this.  Look into parameterized queries, ORMs, etc.  What you have here leaves your database wide open to attack.

Comment: Thanks but now i got "Parameterized query expects a parameter value which was not supplied.
Parameter name: 1" error. Do you want to see Stack Trace?

Comment: @Mato Dobrák Kormuth: I'm not entirely familiar with the objects and methods you're using here.  What type is `Database` in this code?  With that I can potentially look up the expected behavior of the `.Execute` method.

Comment: That link doesn't point to the correct documentation. You need this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.execute%28v=VS.99%29.aspx